# My deep learning network does not recognize empty images

Tags: python, deep-learning

I created a deep learning network that recognizes fish species. It works when there are fish in the image. However, when an image is empty, it wants to identify it as a fish at all costs.
So I created a training category "EMPTY" where I compiled images of different empty seabeds. It doesn't work well or at least not as well as it should. There are some pretty big mistakes that he doesn't normally make and I feel like this empty category is losing him more than anything else.

Do you have any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to get rid of the false detection, a good way is to add a lot of images that does not contain fish species with an empty file for the annotation of this image.
this is mentioned in [link](https://github.com/Angelixus/darknetTFG#how-to-improve-object-detection) Yolov4 repo in GitHub.

> next time please add more information so we know the problem better.